# Why can't I load data over cross domain?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, cordova

I've some problems getting som JSON data from my webhost. So no I have broken down the function only to GET google, and it still does not retrieve the data. Nothing happens, I've added the function below to a button in the app (onclick, return false yada yada):

```
loadGoogle: function () {

  console.log('Lets load Google!');

  $.support.cors = true;
  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'text',
    url: 'http://google.com'
  })
    .done(function (data) { console.log('GOOGLE IS LOADED'); })
    .fail(function (xhr, error, et) { console.log('GOOGLE WAS NOT LOADED'); });

  console.log('The end');
}
```

the output in console during emulating:

```
CommandString : DebugConsole/log/DebugConsole1659732817/"Lets load Google!"
Log:["Lets load Google!","DebugConsole1659732817"]
The thread 0xfb0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
CommandString : DebugConsole/log/DebugConsole1659732818/"The end"
Log:["The end","DebugConsole1659732818"]
The thread 0xff4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

As you can see It output the `log` before AND after the ajax, but not the `done` or `fail` events triggers. And as you see I have enabled cors and allowCrossDomainPages according to [the doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/pages/phonegap.html). So why am I failing at this? Google is not the source I want to read, but I cant even get that to work so...

Comment: Because Google intentionally isn't returning the proper CORS headers.

Answer (score 2):

> And as you see I have enabled cors...

It's not up to **you** to enable CORS (for other people's sites). For you to retrieve data from `google.com`, **they** have to enable CORS and allow your origin to extract data from them. (There's a wildcard, `*`, if they want to allow everyone to load their content.)

Also note that the browser has to [support CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors). All up-to-date modern desktop browsers do, as do most mobile browsers, although note that both IE8 and IE9 require that you use the non-standard `XDomainRequest` object, not `XMLHttpRequest` (they finally get this right in IE10), and jQuery does **not** smooth over that particular cross-browser issue for you (does not, and will not). There are plug-ins that do, though.

If you're in control of the remote end (e.g., the webhost you're retrieving data from), then you can enable CORS at the server level by responding to the preflight call and the `GET` with the appropriate response headers.

More:

- [The CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)
- [Wikipedia: Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
- [CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: My web api is in Azure, and ive enabled cors "all over the place". Still cant get it to work. Maybe you can link one of the plugins u mention?

Comment: @Jason94: I haven't used any personally, but [a search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+xdomainrequest+plugin) should give you several options. But first make it work in something other than IE, just as a matter of breaking the problem up into slices. Read the CORS spec, you have to be pretty precise about the headers you send back in response to the preflight and the actual request. For instance, if the request will include a request header, you have to authorise that request header in the preflight and the response, or the browser will prevent the JavaScript code seeing the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy to route the calls to Google through your web server. If you are using Microsoft IIS, you can use the URL rewrite module as I describe here [cross domain AJAX using proxy](http://www.nathanfox.net/blog/4/Cross-domain-AJAX-call-using-IIS-7-and-Microsoft-URL-Rewrite). If using Apache, you can use mod_proxy to redirect cross domain calls through your website's server.

This might not be ideal, but it might be a reasonable solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsonp instead of Json and you should have no issues:

```
     $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",                                     
        url: 'http://DomainName.com/api.php',  
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
      success: function(data)        
      {
       // append your data
      }
```